# Retrofit 2 sending from android client empty request body to spring boot in server with 200 status whereas in postman it works fine

Tags: android, spring-boot, postman, retrofit2

I have been struggling hard to send a request body to server with one parameter to server from android client, which gives me 200 status on success but with an empty request body. It works all fine in postman with successful transaction.

**API below is what i am calling**

```
@POST("user/loginwithotp")
@Headers({
        "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"
})
Call<ResponseAPI> saveMobile(@Body AuthenticationVO authenticationVO);
```

**Below is the code for retrofit client**

```
                     public static Retrofit getClient() {
        String baseUrl = "http://192.168.xx.xx:8080/dmp/";


        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new   OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

      Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl) //if all api base url is same only add here. If not same then add url as string in “getClient()” method and then pass that here
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(client)
                .build();
        return retrofit;
    }

 public static VuAPIServices geVuAPIServices() {
        VuAPIServices vuAPIServices = getClient().create(VuAPIServices.class);
        return vuAPIServices;
    }
```

}

**Activity code below**

```
    public AuthenticationVO createRequest(){
        customLoader.show();
      AuthenticationVO authenticationVO = new AuthenticationVO ();
          authenticationVO.setMobileNumber(mobileNumber);
        return authenticationVO;

    }
    public void saveMobile(AuthenticationVO authenticationVO){

        Call<ResponseAPI> responseAPICall = ApiClient.geVuAPIServices().saveMobile (authenticationVO);
        responseAPICall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseAPI>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseAPI> call, retrofit2.Response<ResponseAPI> response) {
                customLoader.dismiss();
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d("response", "code = " + response.code());
                    Log.d("response", "code = " + response.body());

//                    sessionManager.setLogin(true);
//                    sessionManager.setLoginMobile(mobileNumber);
//                    Intent home = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VU_OTPHandler.class);
//                    home.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
//                    startActivity(home);
//                    finish();
                } else {
                    Log.i("onEmptyResponse", "Returned empty response");//Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Nothing returned",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
                Toast.makeText(VuLogin.this, "saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseAPI> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(VuLogin.this, "Request Failed "+t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

**Postman images**

[image: image 1]

**This is the controller below on server side i have written**

```
 @PostMapping(path = ENDPOINT_MOBILE_OTP)
    public AuthenticationVO signInWithOTP(@Valid @RequestBody AuthenticationVO authenticationVO){
        System.out.println("login request is:-"+authenticationVO.toString());
        try {
        if (authenticationVO != null && authenticationVO.getMobileNumber()!=null) {
            MultitenantUtility.request = httpRequest;
            String tenantId = multitenantUtility.resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier();
            if (tenantId != null) {
                multitenantUtility.setCurrentTenant(tenantId);
                authenticationVO = userService.checkLoginCredentialsWithOTP(authenticationVO);
            } else {
                System.out.println("request body is empty");
                //throw new DMPBadRequestException("Request body is empty");
            }
            }
        else {
            System.out.println("Mobile Number is mandatory");
            //throw new DMPBadRequestException("Request body is empty");
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Excepton "+e);
        }
        finally
        {
            multitenantUtility.clearThreadLocal();
            LOGGER.info("authenticateUser - before returning");
        }
        
        
        return authenticationVO;
    }
```

Please guys help me on this issue. several days i have spent on trying to make it work many methods i tried but nothing worked. Please help me know what i am missing. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding host in intercept headers and the whole problem soleved.

Thanks especially to @pratik vekariya for your kind efforts

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Replace below line

```
Call<ResponseAPI> saveMobile(@Body AuthenticationVO authenticationVO);
```

with

```
Call<ResponseAPI> saveMobile(@Body RequestBody jsonObject);
```

Now at below line also need to change

```
        Call<ResponseAPI> responseAPICall = ApiClient.geVuAPIServices().saveMobile (authenticationVO);
```

with

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("mobileNumber", 0123456789);
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), (jsonObject.toString()));

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  Call<ResponseAPI> responseAPICall = ApiClient.geVuAPIServices().saveMobile (body);
  //now continue as your code
  responseAPICall.enque.....
```

Also try to change retrofit client with this

```
public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new   OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl) //if all api base url is same only add here. If not same then add url as string in “getClient()” method and then pass that here
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .client(client)
            .build();
    return retrofit;
}
```

Hope this will work

Comment: Hi pratik that's giving me an error for body parameter in this line  Call<ResponseAPI> responseAPICall = ApiClient.geVuAPIServices().saveMobile (body);

Comment: Your code is too sending only empty request to the server whereas in my postman its all working fine, kindly see if something there we are still missing. I am getting 200 status in response but with empty request in server its showing

Comment: @DishaSingh Call<ResponseAPI> responseAPICall = ApiClient.geVuAPIServices().saveMobile (body); this need to put in try block. responseAPICall.enqu.... also need to put in try block.

And please check you have replaced this line "Call<ResponseAPI> saveMobile(@Body AuthenticationVO authenticationVO);"

Comment: I followed the same you suggested pratik but i am surprised that nothing works except postman with my server. i am good in java spring but this pandemic i started learning android. i tried in volley did the json parser or anything nothing worked, now retrofit. Every time request is going empty in server.

Comment: @DishaSingh is there any other parameters you have added in postman in "params" section?

Comment: Only one parameter mobileNumber needs to be sent and it works fine with status 200 and successful response in postman

Comment: @DishaSingh i have added my retrofit client,  add it in your code and try. Because this same setup i have done and its working for all apis. Let me know me if not work.

Comment: That again didn't work, i updated my retrofit client part above. I am going hopeless feel like it won't work

Comment: @DishaSingh something is missing, very small thing is missing. It should work. Is there any authentication added in postman? And at this line what you are getting Log.d("response", "code = " + response.body());  

also add one more condition f (response!=null) before if (response.isSuccessful()) and print log in else and if both

Comment: Those two line now removed forgot that earlier. Pratik i m not adding authentication in the postman as in server side my logic is mobilenumber will be sent in initial user login table there it will look for a mobile in database user table if not there it will save in database and generate otp. Once otp is generated and on next api the otp is sent , there that will generate authToken for user. So in initial user login table no auth is required hence not sending in postman

Comment: I printed the log in response and the E/Success: {"firstLogin":false,"firstTimeLogin":false,"flag":0,"fromInternalApp":false,"locked":false,"mobileNumber":"5236521453","noToken":false,"status":false}

Comment: @DishaSingh so in log {"firstLogin":false,"firstTimeLogin":false,"flag":0,"fromInternalApp":false,"locked":false,"mobileNumber":"5236521453","noToken":false,"status":false}  this response print, but not getting in your model class, am i right?

Comment: Yeah that i am verifying. I appreciate your patience pratik. Updated with my response model class

Comment: Still sending empty request

Comment: @DishaSingh create your pojo from here http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/ 
and pass it every place like Call<ResponseAPI> replace with Call<new_pojo_from_site> and implements it Serializable

Comment: @DishaSingh Basically Problem is with your pojo class because in log reponse print. So response is not adding into pojo class. Probably one of field is incorrect or any value is missing like in response there is 10 field and in pojo may there is 9 field. So this can be problem.

Comment: Pratik thats giving me the same result in response E/Success: {"firstLogin":false,"firstTimeLogin":false,"flag":0,"fromInternalApp":false,"locked":false,"noToken":false,"status":false} after creating pojo on pojo.sodhnalibrary.com

Comment: Pratik thanks for your time. I have lost hope it will work. Will find some other ways than retrofit again. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
        @RequestMapping(
                value = "/",
                method = RequestMethod.POST,
                produces = "application/json"
        )
```

Instead of `@PostMapping("/")`

With that, it will work fine